# a variable for multi function.?

Tags: php, codeigniter

did can be defined a variable for multi function(in codeigniter)? how is it?

because i must use of a value similar in multi function.

**like:**

```
  class Home extends CI_Controller {
   $hi = 'hello'
    function one() {
       echo $hi;
    }
    function tow() {
       echo $hi;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about doing something like this

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {
    protected $_hi = 'hi';
    function one() {
       echo $this->_hi;
    }
    function tow() {
       echo $this->_hi;
    }
  }
```

if the hi is a constant you have better to use the const keyword

```
  class Home extends CI_Controller {
    const HI = 'hi';
    function one() {
       echo self::HI;
    }
    function tow() {
       echo self::HI;
    }
  }
```

last point if that constant is used in more than one controller you have better to create a separate class and define the constant in that class.

```
  class Home extends CI_Controller {
    protected $_find;

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->_find = $this->input->post('find');
    }

    function one() {
       echo $this->_find;
    }
    function tow() {
       echo $this->_find;
    }
  }
```

one remark with the last code snipet, I am not an codeigniter expert so not sure if you can do `$this->input->post('find')` would work in the constructor

Comment: `protected find = $this->input->post('find'); // Line 3` = in function => `$find = $this->find;` this have error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in D:\xampp\htdocs\mehdi\application\controllers\admin\accommodation.php on line 3` ?

Comment: Kate: you cannot set variable with output from a function ... see my edit